# Developer tools not working in Chrome osx

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-inspector

Trying to open developer tools in Chrome, either through the main menu or through inspect elements context option, I see the inspector window flash up and then just disappears. Everytime.

What's going on? Is there anyway of reseting the developer tools configuration without deleting my profile?

I'm using v 26.0.1410.43 on Apple MacBook Pro.

Comment: Is the bug specific to your profile, or Chrome? To find out, launch Chrome using a new profile: `"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever`. If the same problem shows up, try a new installation.

Comment: thanks - its working now on a new installation - and I managed to copy across my bookmarks but I guess if the old profile was corrupt then i have to write everything else off..?

Comment: You can compare the auto-generated files from the new profile (in `/tmp/whatever`) with your existing profile (in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`), and try to copy files forth and back to see if you can reproduce/fix the problem (don't forget to create a back-up).

Comment: Cool, I may have to try something like that - its wierd... while i inspect element window opens (inline to the browser), the same thing happened again when i tried to share a youtube video. New window flashes open then disappears.

Hmm as i wrote that, the blindingly obvious issue just struck - adblock..

Answer (score 5):

I just had a very similar issue where a white window showed up where the dev tools should have been. (I think it was caused by Photoshop CS6 freezing the crap out of my machine every 10 minutes since I updated to Yosemite)

The way I resolved it without having to delete all the rest of my user data was by deleting the following file:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal`

Quit Chrome, delete that file, restart and hopefully you'll be good to go!

(Thanks to Rob W. for the tip on how to run Chrome with a whole new directory setup)