# Chrome Web Dev Tools not showing up on Mac OXS 10.11.2

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, osx-elcapitan

Since two days the Chrome Dev Tools stopped working. I opened/closed Chrome. I restarted my MacBook but nothing worked. I tried to open the Chrome Dev Tools and no window is opening. I tried to solve it with the following trick: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866632/1280401) but I don't have the file `chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal` there. Maybe this is because my problem is slightly different because on my MacBook the Chrome Dev Tools aren't showing up anymore.

When I execute the following command:

`"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever`

Everything works fine again. So I fear that my Chrome Profile is somehow destroyed. Is there a way to get the Chrome Dev Tools working without deleting my Chrome Profile? Deleting the profile would be the worst case. Hope someone could help me.

My Chrome Version is:  48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

My Macbook is: OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 (15C50), MacBook Pro (Retina, 15', Mitte 2014)

EDIT:

I started Chrome with:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging --log-level=0`

Then I got the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object.observe is not a function", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.js (10681)`

After pasting this error into Google I found the following thread https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=549225#.

Is this expected behavior that I can not open the dev tools when javascript-harmony-shipping is turned on? With  javascript-harmony-shipping turned off everything works as expected

[[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866632/1280401](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866632/1280401)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems to be a bug with javascript-harmony-shipping. Further details can be found here: [answer from Paul Irish in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/Fh0Lite-LuE/_5uaAaSjAwAJ)